# Generating a trinomial tree with arrays - Python

Tags: python

I have a very simple problem that I cann't figure out. I have the following code:

```
r = [np.array([100])]
for i in range(2):
  r.append(np.concatenate((r[-1][:1]*1.5, r[-1]*0.5)))
```

This produces at each iteration:

```
[array([100]), array([ 150.,   50.])]

[array([100]), array([ 150.,   50.]), array([ 225.,   75.,   25.])]
```

The idea of this code is to generate a structure similar to a binomial tree with the up=1.5, down=0.5. So from 100 we go up to 150, down to 50. In the next time step, from 150, we go to 225 or 75; and from 50 to 75 or 25.

But now.... I want to use this to generate a trinomial tree. So say up=1.5, middle=stays the same=1, down=0.5.

So the iteration should produce

```
[array([100]), array([ 150., 100.,  50.])]

[array([100]), array([ 150.,  100., 50.]), array([ 225., 150., 75., 150., 100., 75., 75., 50., 25. ])]
```

This generates a kind-of non recombinant structure. But I dont know how to modify the code to get it. The closest I got is:

```
r.append(np.concatenate((r[-1][:1]*1.5,r[-1][:1]*1, r[-1]*0.5)))
```

but this doesnt make the result:

```
[array([100]), array([ 150.,  100.,   50.]), array([ 225.,  150.,   75.,   50.,   25.])]
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Since the first one was recombining, up of down and down of up were producing same result and hence one of them were being ignored in the code.

What you want is a non-recombining structure, so you need to consider all the results, changing this will produce desired results:

```
for i in range(2):
  r.append(np.concatenate((r[-1]*1.5, r[-1], r[-1]*0.5)))

>>> r
[array([100]), array([ 150.,  100.,   50.]), array([ 225.,  150.,   75.,  150.,  100.,   50.,   75.,   50.,   25.])]
```

what it does is take the previous array (r[-1]) and multiplies with 3 multiplier you want and then concatenate() combines these three together.